# Who are these robots?

Tags: character-identification

I came across this image of "Robotic Characters From TV and Film (1927-2012)".

I recognise a few of them, but I don't think I can recognise them *all*.

[image: A poster of 28 robots]

**Who are these robots?**

Comment: Long-time lurker: I only joined to say that the people who make these awesome t-shirts are my next-door neighbours. Want me to pop round and ask for confirmation?

Comment: @indextwo please do!

Comment: @indextwo so did they confirm? :)

Comment: @Jenayah I texted them a link to the thread, and I got back 'Hahahaha' ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 105, accepted):

*This is a Community Wiki answer; feel free to edit it to add new names.*

*Click on the thumbnails to see the full image.*

---

### 1st Row

[image: 1st Row]

1. The Gunslinger, *Westworld (1973)*

   [image: Gunslinger]
2. Cylon, *Battlestar Galactica* (original series)

   [image: Cylon]
3. Nomad, *Star Trek*

   [image: Nomad]
4. K-9, *Doctor Who*

   [image: K9]
5. Mechani-Kong, *King Kong Escapes*

   [image: Mechani-Kong]
6. Huey, Dewey, or Louie, *Silent Running*

   [image: Huey, Dewey, or Louie]
7. C-3PO, *Star Wars*

   [image: C-3P0]

### 2nd Row

[image: 2nd row]

1. The Iron Giant, *The Iron Giant*

   [image: Iron Giant]
2. Robby the Robot, *Forbidden Planet* (1956)

   [image: Robby]
3. Mechagodzilla, *Mechagodzilla* (1974)

   [image: MechaGodzilla]
4. Flotsam, *Batteries Not Included*

   [image: Flotsam]
5. Gort, *The Day the Earth Stood Still*

   [image: GORT]
6. T-800, *Terminator*

   [image: Terminator]
7. ED-209, *RoboCop*

   [image: ED-209]

### 3rd Row

[image: 3rd row]

1. Carmen, *Batteries Not Included*

   [image: Carmen]
2. Police Android, *THX1138*

   [image: Police Android]
3. Maximilian, *The Black Hole*

   [image: Maximilian]
4. R2-D2, *Star Wars*

   [image: R2-D2]
5. IG-88B, *Star Wars*

   [image: IG-88B]
6. Bender, *Futurama*

   [image: Bender]
7. Robocop, *Robocop*

   [image: Robocop]

### 4th Row

[image: 4th row]

1. Maschinenmensch, *Metropolis*

   [image: Maschinenmensch]
2. Twiki, *Buck Rogers in the 25th Century*

   [image: Twiki]
3. Marvin, *Hitchikers Guide To The Galaxy* (the [1981 miniseries](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081874/), not the [2005 film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371724/))

   [image: Marvin]
4. V.I.N.CENT, *The Black Hole*

   [image: V.I.N.CENT]
5. T-1000, *Terminator 2*

   [image: T-1000]
6. WALL·E, *WALL·E*

   [image: WALL-E]
7. Number "Johnny" 5, *Short Circuit*

   [image: Number 5]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77940/discussion-on-answer-by-sqb-who-are-these-robots).